# How To Use array_search In Following Case Scenario

Tags: php

Here's the code I'm using, but it's not working:

```
$if_existing = "Aishwarya Majmudar";
$key = array_search($if_existing, array_column($all_tags, 'name'));
if($key){
echo 'Yes';
}

Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 57
            [name] => Aishwarya Majmudar
            [slug] => aishwarya-majmudar
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 57
            [taxonomy] => post_tag
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 60
            [name] => Akull
            [slug] => akull
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 60
            [taxonomy] => post_tag
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )
```

)

I want to look if the name-value exists in the given array or not. It looks like array_search is the best function that I can use but it's not working in the array I've provided.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php: _“Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.”_

Comment: The key of your array item in which the value you are looking for _is_ found, is `0`. `if(0)` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster and more resource efficient if you would use the [FilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) class. Here 's a short example.

```
class NameFilterIterator extends FilterIterater
{
    protected string $name;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept(): bool
    {
        $term = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return $term->name === $this->name;
    }
}
```

This is an FilterIterator inheritance. This class takes a name attribute in the constructor and then it searches for the name in your array. Since your collection is an array of WP_Term objects, you can use the object-notation to get `WP_Term` properties. Let us have a look how to use this.

Assuming your WP_Term collection is stored in $result.

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($result);
$filter = new NameFilterIterator($iterator, 'Aishwarya Majmudar');

foreach ($filter as $term) {
    var_dump($term); // returns the term with Aishwarya Majmudar
}
```

The foreach loop now returns just the terms, which name property is 'Aishwarya Majmudar'. Both the ArrayIterator class and the FilterIterator class come with PHP and are already available. You can simply use them. They are faster and more resource efficient than the array functions. Just insert the `NameFilterIterator` class in your functions.php file of your theme and you can use it all over again.

Comment: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: This error occurs, when your PHP version is < 7.4. Just leave out the type hints before the class attributes or update to the newest PHP version.